# Why is the sender of the email the same email that should be the receiver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, gmail, nodemailer

I'm doing a contact form for my small training project.
Email is being received, but it doesn't seem right. It appears that I'm sending it to myself from the same email account

I'm using nodemailer and Angular.

This is the sendEmail function :

```
async function sendEmail(user,callback){
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:587,
    service: `gmail`,
    auth:{
      async function sendEmail(data,callback){


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:587,
    service: `gmail`,
    auth:{
        user : `youremailwithoutprovider`,
        pass: `your 3rd party app Google password`
    }
})

 const mailOptions = {
  sender: data.email,
  to: `AUTH USER SHOULD BE HERE`,
  subject: data.subject,
  query: data.query,
  html: `
  <h2>From:</h2>
  <div>${data.email}</div>
  <h2>Subject:</h2>
  <div>${ data.subject}</div>
  <h2>Query:</h2>
  <div>${ data.query}</div>
  `
}

let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

callback(info)
}

module.exports = {
  sendEmail
}
```

This is the controller in the server:

```
emailController.post(`/contact-us`, (req,res) => {
    console.log(`request came`)
    let user = req.body
   

    try {
        sendEmail(user,callback => {
      
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error:error.message})
    }

    res.end()
})
```

This is the whole contact-us component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactUsService } from './contact-us.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-us',
  templateUrl: './contact-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-us.component.css']
})
export class ContactUsComponent {
  errors: any;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private emailService: ContactUsService, private router: Router ){}

  contactUs = this.fb.group({
    name: [``,[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    subject: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    email: [``,[Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    query: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(15)]]
  })  

  sendEmail(){
  let user = {
    name : this.contactUs.get(`name`)?.value,
    email : this.contactUs.get(`email`)?.value,
    subject : this.contactUs.get(`subject`)?.value,
    query:  this.contactUs.get(`query`)?.value,
  } 
  this.emailService.sendEmail(user).subscribe({
    

      next: () => this.router.navigate([`/`]),
      error:(err)=>   {
        this.errors = err.error?.error
      }

    })
  
    this.contactUs.reset()
  
  }
}
```

This is the service in Angular :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IQuery } from '../interfaces/query';

const API_CONTACT_US_EMAIL = `http://localhost:3000/contact-us`

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactUsService {

  query : null | IQuery | undefined
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  sendEmail(data: {}){
    return this.http.post<IQuery>(`${API_CONTACT_US_EMAIL}`, data)
  }
}
```

This is all working, form is being filled out properly, email is received, just the sender is wrong in the gmail - it is the same email address.

You can see that I've used console.log a few times on the server, from them it seems like the proper data is being picked up, but something happens in the nodemailer I think.

```
request came
 Email sent
```

What did I miss here?

Thanks

Comment: the sender is the SMTP account you are logged into.   You can't send it on behalf of someone not logged in

Comment: What is the proper way to make it work the way I want? I need to see who the email is coming from and be able to reply to it. I mean user wants to contact me, I will need to see who that user is

Comment: I would go though the Gmail API and use oauth2 to request authorization of the owner of the account.  it would be easier than getting xoauth2 working with nodejs

Comment: It is doable through nodemailer and it is the way with the least resistance as this is a simple uni project. Thank you for your time though! Appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe you want to remove the password from your question, just a heads-up. Other than that, you might as well just put the requesting email into the "text" that you send, given that you seek for a fast and simple solution :)

Comment: Yes, thank you for the comment, just noticed this myself and removed them. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I updated the sendEmail function to show me good experience on the email. Not the prettiest, but you can change the css however you find appropriate:

```
async function sendEmail(data,callback){
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:587,
    service: `gmail`,
    auth:{
        user : `youremailwithoutprovider`,
        pass: `your 3rd party app Google password`
    }
})

 const mailOptions = {
  sender: data.email,
  to: `essentialoilsnodemailer@gmail.com`,
  subject: data.subject,
  query: data.query,
  html: `
  <h2>From:</h2>
  <div>${data.email}</div>
  <h2>Subject:</h2>
  <div>${ data.subject}</div>
  <h2>Query:</h2>
  <div>${ data.query}</div>
  `
}
//console.log(mailOptions)
let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

callback(info)
}

module.exports = {
  sendEmail
}
```

Also as this is the most recent case I`ve found on gmail and nodemailer, now you need to enable 2FA and create a separate app password to put in the node authentication/ transport. The previous setting to allow less secure applications is outdated now